# Counterexample to the structure of commutative rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Every finite commutative ring $R$ must be of the form $\frac{ \mathbb{Z} }{n_1 \mathbb{Z}} \times \frac{\mathbb{Z}}{n_2 \mathbb{Z}} \times \dots \frac{\mathbb{Z}}{n_k \mathbb{Z}}$.

I am unable to find a counterexample. I heard that a field of order $4$ works, but I cannot see the reason. Can anyone explain why a field of order $4$ cannot be of the form above.

Comment: You should just ask for clarification of the comment in your first post, rather than making an entirely new one just for the comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there are at least two factors (with $n_k\ne1$) in the product, then for sure the product has non-trivial zero divisors, which $\Bbb F_4$ can't have. The only $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$ with four elements is $\Bbb Z/4\Bbb Z$, which is not a field.

Comment: It might add clarity to note that "if there are at least two factors in the product" only allows the possibility $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$.

Comment: @GregMartin In truth, it isn't quite the point that I was making, but yes it's a valid remark.

Answer (score 2):

Paraphrasing Gae. S.'s answer:

- Finite fields are finite commutative rings
- Finite field do not have zero devisors (because they are fields)
- Every ring of the form $\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{n_1\mathbb{Z}}\times ...\times \frac{\mathbb{Z}}{n_k\mathbb{Z}}$ has zero devisors unless it is $\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{p\mathbb{Z}}$ for some prime $p$ in which case it has $p$ elements. But it can't be $p=4$.